# Joining two time intensive SQL queries into one more streamlined

Tags: sql

I have two similar sql statements that return the name of a computer that has a specific filename running on it, e.g. OUTLOOK.EXE and EXCEL.EXE they both return the computer names seperately but I wnat to see the computers that are running both at the same time. I have a query that does it but it is time intensive and runs and runs and runs. Any ideas how to streamline these two queries in a more streamlined version. here is an example of the queries, since they are the same I am just showing one.

```
select CompName, FileName, FileDescription, FileVersion, FileSize, FileModifiedDate, FilePath
From Table
join Table on SYRID = SFID
Where FileName LIKE 'OUTLOOK.EXE' AND SF.FileVersion LIKE '14.%' AND FilePath LIKE 'C:\Program Files%'
ORDER BY CompName
```

I renamed everything for sake of privacy, but the jest of the query is there. I have the second one just for a different filename. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I wouldn't use "Like" statement when an exact match is desired. You also give no indications as to information like indexes, etc. for the tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
select compname from
(
        select CompName
        From Table
        Where ( FileName = 'OUTLOOK.EXE' AND SF.FileVersion LIKE '14.%' ) 
        OR ( FileName = 'EXCEL.EXE' AND SF.FileVersion LIKE '12.%' )
        AND FilePath LIKE 'C:\Program Files%'
)
having count(*) > 1
group by compname
ORDER BY CompName
```

Comment: I would want an "AND" instead of the "OR" b/c I am looking for both running on one computer, not either or. I'm not sure if it resolves my time intensive issue, but it does do a nice job of combining them.